# Google Slides - Change Shape Adjustments from script

Tags: google-apps-script

Some shapes e.g. in Google Slides have kind of markers to adjust the shapes design.
(Example Pie-Shape, Arrow-Shape)

This is working in the UI very well, but **how to adjust it, using g-script**.

[Markers - see yellow boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvATS.png)

In MS-Office VBA such is called Adjustments and we can get a Array of all this markers to change it.

After several hours searching the Google Apps Api and the internet I stopped frustrated searching because I didn't find anything promising.

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape) you can find all available methods applicable to Slides shapes via Apps Script. As you see, the choices are a bit limited. You can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) to ask for the implementation of shape adjustments.

Comment: Many thanks for this ...
I have created a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193348441